# Mathematical equations with imported excel coordinates

Tags: python, math, plot, coordinates

I have like 10 or more *x* and *y* coordinates, and also an equation for them. And I can't figure out how make those calculations - especially a part with the equations. First of all, let's say there are 5 coordinates:

[image: In excel]

and I need to apply this equation:

[image: Equations]

The first one is the main, and those two others are for control check. How could I make it so it would read those coordinates and calculate according to equation? I tried:

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('coordinates.xlsx')
sheet = book.active
for row_i in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
x_value = sheet.cell(row=row_i, column=1).value
y_value = sheet.cell(row=row_i, column=2).value
print(x_value,y_value)
```

I am stuck at making calculations and managing the whole process after inputing values. Moreover, it needs to accept as many coordinates as there are and it counts the area plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top equation seems to suggest that you would do:

```
two_p = 0
for row_i in range(1, sheet.max_row - 1):
    x_i = float(sheet.cell(row=row_i, column=1).value)
    y_plus1 = float(sheet.cell(row=row_i+1, column=2).value)
    y_minus1 = float(sheet.cell(row=row_i-1, column=2).value)
    two_p += x_i*(y_plus1 - y_minus1)
print(two_p)
```

Is this what you had in mind? You would do something similar for the control equations.

EDIT: Added `float` conversion in the formulas above in case the data coming from excel is wrongly formatted.

Comment: Kinda, but the two_p += x_i*(y_plus1 - y_minus1) is not correct(unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'). How I understood the problem of it was, that you need append those coordinates. Instead of this I picked previous code and defined polygon coordinates by polygon.append([x,y]), then I used formulas. If I'm wrong, please correct me. Sometime It is possible that I don't understand errors or code right, cause of inexperience or language barrier.

Comment: @jayprod That means something is wrong from the data coming from excel. You could try to make sure to convert it to `float` before using it -- see my answer. For the equation you showed me there is no reason to append anything to a list -- `P` is a single value calculated from two lists (`X` and `Y`) which you already have. Try the updated version, and if it doesn't work post an update in your original question with the error message.